# how to write loop statement in sql to get values in one parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

i am so new to t-sql in sql server. how to loop through select result. example here:

```
Table:
ItemName     Value
XPS_Paid     XPSP001
XPS_UnPaid   XPSUP001   


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_vendor_config]
@PCType nvarchar(50),
@vendor nvarchar(50),
@param nvarchar(50) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
IF @PCType= 'XPS'
SELECT @param = p.Value
FROM    Vendors v
JOIN    PConfig p ON v.VendorId = p.Vendor_Id
JOIN    ConfigItems c ON p.ConfigId = c.ConfigId 
WHERE   v.Description = @vendor
AND     ItemName IN ('XPS_Paid', 'XPS_UnPaid')
```

This result is:
@param = XPSP001

I expect the result: 
@param = XPSP001 
@param =  XPSUP001

Something like : while (@param.count < 0 ) to get two values. but how to convert string parameter into int. and how to write while statement in select statement. Need to pass these values into listbox in C#.

Can you please give me example code?

Comment: not clear what you want, this is a list separated by spaces?  you might want `@param` to be `nvarchar(max)` in that case, could get big

Comment: no it is not spaces i am looking for. i just need to get two values in one parameter. would loop statment work?

Comment: If you are not going to separate them by spaces and they are going to be in a single varchar what are you going to separate them by?

Comment: something like : while (@param.count < 0) but this paramater is string. how to convert into int. i want to list two values so that i can pass these values into C# that contains listbox.

Comment: You don't use loops in sql.  and now you are talking about ints.  What part of `"I expect the result @param = XPSP001 XPSUP001"` has an int in it?  Voting to close

Comment: Now your question makes no sense with @param listed twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case, you could do:

```
SELECT @param = min(p.Value) + ' ' + max(p.Value)
FROM    Vendors v
JOIN    PConfig p ON v.VendorId = p.Vendor_Id
JOIN    ConfigItems c ON p.ConfigId = c.ConfigId 
WHERE   v.Description = @vendor
AND     ItemName IN ('XPS_Paid', 'XPS_UnPaid')
```

As a more general solution, you would need to concatenate the strings in the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

While you can write loops in TSQL you typically don't.  SQL is about manipulating whole sets of data at one time.  In fact you probably want to return a table of the results not a string.

However, here is how you do what you are asking for:

```
SELECT  @param = p.Value
FROM
( 
 SELECT  p.Value
 FROM    Vendors v
 JOIN    PConfig p ON v.VendorId = p.Vendor_Id
 JOIN    ConfigItems c ON p.ConfigId = c.ConfigId 
 WHERE   v.Description = @vendor
 AND     ItemName IN ('XPS_Paid', 'XPS_UnPaid')
 FOR XML PATH(' ')
) p
```

Comment: i test your example... it seems not working because i get only one value. im sorry for making unclear. i just update my post :)

Comment: Then there is only one value

Answer (score 0):

> Need to pass these values into listbox in C#.

If you need get values for listbox, then just:

- create a instance of `DataTable`
- fill this `DataTable` with your data
- assign this `DataTable` object to `yourlistbox.DataSource`.

SQL query for getting data will be then:

```
SELECT p.Value
FROM    Vendors v
JOIN    PConfig p ON v.VendorId = p.Vendor_Id
JOIN    ConfigItems c ON p.ConfigId = c.ConfigId 
WHERE   v.Description = @vendor
AND     ItemName IN ('XPS_Paid', 'XPS_UnPaid')
```

Just add same parameters (@vendor) to SQLCommand

Assume that check of

> IF @PCType= 'XPS'

you can do in C# code before running query